# DurandalJs: A generic solution to put focus to the first input element on the composed view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I'm wondering if there is a generic solution to put a focus to the first input/contenteditable field on the composed view.

I'm able to do this in each of my viewModels by subscribing to the specific lifecycle event, but I'm not able to do this in a more generic way - it would be great to subscribe only once in one specific place.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that `knockout` or `durandal` related ?

Comment: It is durandal related, I want to put focus after view composition

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but you may [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/nDwGC/).

Comment: Can't you just put this into the `bindingComplete` method in `binder.js` (which is a noop by default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Enclose your view's html inside a root section or div.
2. add data-bind="focusFirstEditable: true" to this root element.
3. Create a custom binding handler by that name and put your logic to look for the first element that is editable and set the focus in the init of your custom bindingHandler.
4. Add your custom binding handler to composition.addHandler(yourCustomBindingHandler).

This will create a lazy binding that will happen after your compose is complete and it is centralized. whichever view you want this to happen, just add it to the root element.